# Pointing out typos to prospective employer

Tags: hiring-process

When applying to various companies/organisations in the past, sometimes I encountered very obvious and ugly typos in their job-description, assignments or even their website. Sometimes I pointed out these typos to the prospective employer, with the idea of looking secure and with attention to details. Other times I didn't because I didn't want to come across as a smart-ass right away.

I love to hear the ideas of others regarding this issue.

Comment: @sf02: They would likely reject the candidate - do you recommend the same for a candidate in this time regardless of industry? Or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: @guest I think they meant that the company is unlikely to send back a proofread version of a candidate's resume. In most cases they probably wouldn't even tell the candidate that their resume had problems.

Answer (score 13):

**I wouldn't. Embarrassment makes people unhappy, even if they claim something is important.**

I had a professor in university who would go on and on about the need to avoid mistakes and check your work. I actually still have the syllabus bit for it. It had things like this:

[image]

I would peg that as a one off if other assignments did not have things like this:

[image]

People who pointed these out were ignored or sniped at. And this was someone who openly claimed to value attention to detail and teamwork.

Anecdotally, in my own life, I have gained far more by letting the errors other make slide than challenging them. Unsolicited help is rarely valued.

Comment: It can even come across as petty.

Comment: Got to love the 3 different spellings of capacity though.

Comment: @jcmack https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgqudioHmTE&feature=youtu.be&t=1004 what that always makes me think.

Comment: Your professor didn’t pay attention to details, Donald Knuth pays attention to details.  Of course there’s only one of him...

Answer (score 2):

That would be extremely brave, and I mean brave in the **EXACTLY** the way an MP would mean it when referring to another MP's idea in parliament.

You never make an issue of someone's mistakes in the business world unless you are out to make an enemy

Comment: Oh yes. People take it personal. And that creates an enemy for eternity.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it could be beneficial.

Are you applying as a PR person or someone who would be involved in the contents vof the site in a direct way? Point out how these issues could be damaging their brand and how you would ensure that it doesn't happen again.

Otherwise I would leave it be. As other posters have pointed out, you only risk embarrassing them.